# Rxjs: "throw" statement not being handled by piped catchError

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

A "authenticationService" provides the following authenticate method. I'm unable to enter the piped catchError. What am I missing?

```
authenticate(credentials: { username: string; password: string }){

   return new Observable<any>((observer: Observer<any>) => {

    // ... calling the service, obtaining a promise
    const authenticationPromise = ... ;

    // This is a promise, it must be converted to an Observable
    authenticationPromise
        .then(() => {
          observer.next('ok');
          observer.complete();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('service error ' + err);
          throw new Error('crap');
        });
    });
  }
```

Setting all the ngrx & ngrx/effect part aside, this authentication method is called upon user request:

```
(redux stuff).(({ payload }: actions.LoginRequestAction) =>
    context.authService.authenticate(payload)
    .pipe(
      map(() => new GenericSuccessAction(...))
      // Even though a throw statement happened in the authenticate method, this is never reached:
      catchError((err: Error) => {
        console.log('[debug] error caught: ', err);
        return of(new actions.LoginFailureAction());
      }),
    )
  )
```

Comment: You're not returning an observable in your authenticate method. Try something like `return from(your_promise_here)` in the end of it

Comment: my mistake in the question, the observable is actually returned. I fixed my question. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: you don't need to create an observable like that, just use `return from(your_promise_here)` (`from` is a rxjs creation method)

Comment: Instead of throwing, call `observer.error`, passing the error you want reported.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Operator "from" is definitely a keeper! And the observer.error nailed it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As stated [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html), catchError is used to:
>
> Gracefully handle errors in an observable sequence.

First of all, you are basically handling the error in your promise by catching the error in your promise. Throwing the error in the promise doesn't return an observable that emits an error.

You can:

1. Convert your promise into an observable and don't use `.catch` at all.
2. Return the error as an observable with rxjs' `throwError(err)`

Either way, the way you create your observable is questionable.

This is a much better and concise way to handle promises in rxjs:

```
from(authenticationPromise)
    .pipe(
         map(() => 'ok')
    )
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks. Also, in my case the root cause of the issue was linked to using "throw" instead of observer.error and passing it an Error child class.